# Printing all users in a Firebase Snapshot that have a specific Child with a Specific word?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

```
"users" : {
  "1ZWT7FAE2qThNQfBj7tbMO7BnMo1" : {
    "Coordinates" : {
       "latitude" : 50.054738,
       "longitude" : 8.226809826085624
    "Email" : mark@gmail.com
```

Say you have a child ("Email") for all users. Now you make a Snapshot to check all the emails of all users. The logged in user has an @gmail account. You print all the user that have the same Email domain as the logged in user, @gmail for example. Probably something like the below where the Bold line needs to be figured out

refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

```
if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
    
    self.users.removeAll()
    
    for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        
        if users.key != thisUsersUid {
            print("userskey",users.key)
            
            let usersObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let usersEmail = peopleObject?["Email"] as? String
            ......
            let A = users.childSnapshot(forPath: “Email)
            **if  A@ = the @ of  thisUsersUid** {
                
                let u = Userx(Email: peopleEmail, .........)
                
                self.users.append(u)
                
            } else {
                print ("w")
            }
        } else {
            print ("a")
            
        }
    }}
}   
}
})
```

Below is how I am actually creating the full email. This is being added after the first answer:

```
    @IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (emailField.text ?? ""), password: (passwordField.text ?? ""))  { (user, error) in
        if let _eror = error {
            //something bad happning
            print(_eror.localizedDescription )
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Entry or Duplicate.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }else{
            //user registered successfully
            print(user as Any)
            if let userID = user?.user.uid
            {
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID), forKey: "uid")
                
                let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                
                databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("users").setValue(self.emailField.text!)
                databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("postID").setValue(userID)
                
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and that code **really** needs to be formatted so it's readable. Are you asking if you can do a partial string search in Firebase?

Comment: @Jay Sorry for formatting. I just corrected that. I'll lookup partial string search(hadn't heard the phrase), but that sound like the correct description. Basically every user has a Child(Email). I want to do a Firebase snapshot to see which users have the same @ domain as the logged in user. So say Snapshot finds logged user has @ gmail, then I want to print all the other users who also have @ gmail in the Email child.

Comment: You can't directly do a partial string search with Firebase. However, there are options. Let me post a quick conceptual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not offer a true partial string search - there are ways to search for the front of a string but no way to search the back of a string e.g. you can search for a first name steve in this list

```
frank@mac.com
steve@gmail.com
larry@mac.com
```

but you can't search for gmail.com.

The way to handle it is upfront, when the user enters their email address initially, break it down in code into the respective components; the user name and then the domain name and store those as two child notes within Firebase

```
 steve  @  gmail.com
  ^          ^
username   domain
```

Then your searches for gmail.com are easy.

Your users node will now look like tis

```
firebase
   users
      uid_0
         email_name: "frank"  //the logged in user
         email_domain: "mac.com"
      uid_1
         email_name: "steve"
         email_domain: "gmail.com"
      uid_2
         email_name: "larry"
         email_domain: "mac.com"
```

Then to get all users that have the same domain as the logged in user here's the Firebase code. Note that we get all of the matching users, and then remove the current user from the snapshot.

```
func queryForDomainMatch() {
    let myDomain = "mac.com" //read from my users node
    let myUid = "uid_0" //the users uid - user 'frank' in this case
    let ref = self.ref.child("users") //self.ref points to MY firebase
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "email_domain").queryEqual(toValue: myDomain)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        if let index = allUsers.firstIndex(where: { $0.key == myUid } ) {
            allUsers.remove(at: index) //remove the current user
        }
        for userSnap in allUsers {
            let name = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "email_name").value as! String
            print(name)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output will be the names of the matching nodes

```
larry
```

**EDIT**

To split the email, just use the Swift split function on the string. It will separate the string into an array of username and domain. Like this

```
let email = "jay@mac.com"
let components = email.split(separator: "@")
components.forEach { print($0) }
```

and the output

```
jay
mac.com
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting solution. What I'll probably end up doing is keeping the email child as is (cause it is used elsewhere) and just adding 2 more childs. Once you have the 2 childs though, how would you check if it is the same as the logged in user? You can't just check if A in my code = atgmail.com cause the logged in user might be at Mac.com. In my code I specifically used if users.key != thisUsersUid because I need the user to not be included in what I defined as u in my code.

Comment: *how would you check if it is the same as the logged in user* - that depends on what your use case is. It's not clear in the question what exactly your query is checking for. That being said, if you query all nodes that are `@gmail.com` and the currently logged in user is `@aol.com` you are obviously not going to read the currently logged in users node at all. You current technique is sound; if a node is read in and its key matches the current users uid, ignore it.  `users.key != thisUsersUid`

Comment: _It's not clear in the question what exactly your query is checking for_ - after the logged in user is excluded via **users.key != thisUsersUid**, it checks in a snapshot what the Email of all other users is. Regarding the original answer, how would you actually split the Email into two childs? I added how I am currently making the complete child in the question

Comment: @uuuuuu I updated the question and added the code you need as well. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I am busy working it. It looks good. Just at components.forEach { print($0) }, how do you get that to 2 child instead of print? Maybe something like let components.forEach = (//A,B)? I am googling for that right now, just though you may know.

Comment: @uuuuuu That line was just used to print the elements in the `components` array. Element 0 is the name `components[0]` and the domain is element 1 `components[1]`

Comment: The issue I still have is defining myDomain via snapshot and then using it. I could easily say   `if users.key == thisUsersUid { let myDomain = people.childSnapshot(forPath: "email_domain").value as? String},` but then I couldn't use it for the rest. This code is already happening in the     `for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {`
line of the question

Comment: I think I got it: 
             `if people.key == thisUsersUid {
                  let myDomain = people.childSnapshot(forPath: "e2").value as? String
                self.bSnap = myDomain
             }


                    let myUid = self.bSna `

Comment: so I looked at it again. It works, but name appears to be in String? form. How does one get that in and array?

Comment: @uuuuuu That's not String? form, that's called an optional and it is that because it's what you told it to be `people.childSnapshot(forPath: "e2").value as? String` as? means it's an optional. You should *really* take time and gain an understanding and how to protect your code in case of nil. I like the nil coalescing operator which is ?? which means that if the result is nil, use a non-nil default value; `childSnapshot(forPath: "e2").value as? String ?? "No Value"`  Check out [Optionals](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

Comment: gocha. I got mixed up in the semantics. Thanks. I read the link.